# Deleted nvidia drivers and reinstalled, now plasma wont open

Tags: ubuntu, kde, nvidia, kubuntu, plasma

For some silly reason I did `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-* cuda-*`

Reinstalled the bash script from vnidias website for new drivers

Rebooted

Now kde plasma wont open

If I try `kstart5 plasmashell` i get the following error

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not load the Qt platform "xcb"
```

I can get to a TTY terminal but nothing seems to work for me that i've tried.

I know i've royally messed up, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Never install the nvidia-drivers by other means than your package manager. See answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717923/how-to-install-matching-version-of-nvidia-cuda-toolkit/718891#718891

Comment: Yeah I know this, that's why I'm here. I've admitted I messed up ha

Comment: Then try installing them with your package manager ! :-P

Comment: Err don't ask how but I've removed the /etc/apt/source file too. Kill me now

Comment: Would https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories help you ?